# How to calculate discount, TAX (VAT), Subtotal and Grand Total In a dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I just started with jQuery so im a still a newbie. Could somebody please help me with how to calculate the new price in a dynamic table. I have a dynamic table  with 3 columns, Qty, Discount and Price. I need to recalculate the new price after a user enter a discount(%) in the same textbox the current price is, the subtotal and the grand total.

Here is my table:

```
            <table class="table">
                <thead><tr><th style="width:60%">Description</th><th class="centrer" style="width:10%">Qty</th><th class="centrer" style="width:10%">Discount</th><th class="centrer" style="width:20%">Price</th></tr></thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                if(isset($listeArticlePourUnDossier) && count($listeArticlePourUnDossier) > 0)
                {
                    $sousTotal = 0;
                    $symbol = '';
                    $VAT = 0;
                    $TTC = 0;
                    $iArticles = 0;
                    while($iArticles < count($listeArticlePourUnDossier))
                    {
                        $ARTICLE_CURRENCY = $listeArticlePourUnDossier[$iArticles]['ARTICLE_CURRENCY'];
                        $sousTotal = $sousTotal + ($listeArticlePourUnDossier[$iArticles]['ARTICLE_PRIX']); 
                ?>  
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo ($listeArticlePourUnDossier[$iArticles]['ARTICLE_NOM']); ?></td>
                            <td class="centrer">1</td>
                            <td class="centrer"><input type="text" name="txtdiscount" id="txtdiscount_<?php echo $iArticles; ?>" onkeyup="calc()"/></td>
                            <td class="centrer"><input type="text" name="txtPrice" id="txtPrice_<?php echo $iArticles; ?>" readonly value="<?php echo (number_format($listeArticlePourUnDossier[$iArticles]['ARTICLE_PRIX'],2)); ?>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                <?php       
                    $iArticles++;
                    }
                ?>      
                    <tr>
                        <td class="nocolor"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="centrer bold">Subtotal</td>
                        <td class="centrer bold"><?php echo (number_format($sousTotal,2)); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="nocolor"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="centrer bold">VAT</td>
                        <td class="centrer"><?phpecho (number_format($VAT,2)); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="nocolor"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="centrer bold">G.Total</td>
                        <td class="centrer bold">
                            <?php
                                $TTC = $sousTotal - $VAT;
                                echo (number_format($TTC,2)); 
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }   
                ?>  
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

How to fill up the new price in the current price textbox as soon as a user enter a discount say 10%?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the discounted amount in the price field like this, please check the below code, Hope it will help,

Here, updated td's, which you are using and js code.

Thanks.

```
    <td class="centrer">
                <input type="text" name="txtdiscount" value ="" id="txtdiscount_<?php echo $iArticles; ?>" onkeyup="calc(this.value,'<?php echo $iArticles; ?>')"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="centrer">
                <input type="text" name="txtPrice" id="txtPrice_<?php echo $iArticles; ?>" readonly value="<?php echo (number_format($data['price'],2)); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_txtPrice" id="hidden_txtPrice_<?php echo $iArticles; ?>" readonly value="<?php echo (number_format($data['price'],2)); ?>" />
              </td>


<tr>
        <td class="nocolor"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="centrer bold">VAT</td>
        <td class="centrer">
          <select name="vatDropdown" id="vatDropdown">
            <option value="-1">Select VAT</option>
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
            <option value="2">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="nocolor"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="centrer bold">G.Total</td>
        <td class="centrer bold" id="grandtotal">
          <?php  echo (number_format($TTC,2)); ?>          
        </td>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden_total" id="hidden_total" value="<?php echo (number_format($TTC,2)); ?>" />
      </tr>

        <script>
          function calc(discount, article_id)
          {
            var price = 0;
            var dis_amt = 0;
            var calculatedAmt = 0;
            var discount_amt = 0;
            price = $("#hidden_txtPrice_"+article_id).val();
            if(discount != '')
            {      
              dis_amt = parseFloat(discount) / 100;
              calculatedAmt = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(dis_amt);
              discount_amt = parseFloat(price) - parseFloat(calculatedAmt);
              $("#txtPrice_"+article_id).val(discount_amt);
            }
            else
            {
              $("#txtPrice_"+article_id).val(price);
            }    
          }

$("#vatDropdown").on('change', function(){
    var dropdown_val = $(this).val();
    var grandtotal = $("#hidden_total").val();
    if(dropdown_val == '1')
    {
      var vat_dis = 15 / 100;
      var vat_amt = parseFloat(grandtotal) * parseFloat(vat_dis);
      var gTotal = parseFloat(grandtotal) + parseFloat(vat_amt);
      $("#grandtotal").html(gTotal.toFixed(2));

    }
    else
    {
      $("#grandtotal").text(grandtotal);
    }    
  });

        </script>
```

Comment: i have another related issue....I need to place a dropdown box near VAT for a user to select yes or no. If  "yes", the grandtotal should changed : subtotal - 15%..ant any idea how i should go about this?

Comment: @Dave, I updated the code, please check once again, here 2 more tr which I added and js code in the last. Hope it will solve your issue, Thanks.